# Anyone know of a good example of a PHP system command line zip

Tags: php, command-line, zip

This is another question based on an answer that was given to me.

What I need is the ability to do a system command line zip of large files based on what the web user selects and then prompt them or force a download.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

This can definitely be done - in fact there are many different ways to do it.  One way would be to use the PHP Zip extension (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) to make the file archive.  Then, to let the user download the file, you'll need to set the headers of your download page, like so:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to phpMyAdmin's implementation as an example of a PHP-only implementation.  Download it at [phpmyadmin.net](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and see `libraries/zip.lib.php`.

Answer (score 0):

How about [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/)?

Comment: Most (Windows) users won't have something like 7-zip to open these though :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use the zip/unzip linux utilities?
run 'zip --help' in a linux commandline for details

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using wonderful (and simple) PCLZip library:
http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/index.en.php

You can then send the file with the headers as proposed above.